# Efficient way to load .npz with Tensorflow iterator

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a large `.npz` numpy training file that I want to read more efficiently. I tried to follow the approach from Tensorflow documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays):

> As an alternative, you can define the Dataset in terms of
>   tf.placeholder() tensors, and feed the NumPy arrays when you
>   initialize an Iterator over the dataset.

However after implementing iterator, my model consumes even 2x more memory. Do you have any clues what might be wrong here?

```
def model(batch_size):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, IMGSIZE,IMGSIZE,1])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, n_landmark * 2])
    z = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, ])

    Ret_dict['x'] = x
    Ret_dict['y'] = y
    Ret_dict['z'] = z
    Ret_dict['iterator'] = iter_

   dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y, z)).batch(batch_size)
   iter_ = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
   InputImage, GroundTruth, GroundTruth_Em = iter_.get_next()

   Conv1a = tf.layers.conv2d(InputImage,64,3,1,..)
   (...)


def main():
    trainSet = np.load(args.datasetDir)
    Xtrain = trainSet['Image']
    Ytrain = trainSet['Label_1']
    Ytrain_em = trainSet['Label_2']

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        my_model = model(BATCH_SIZE)
        Saver = tf.train.Saver()
        Saver.restore(sess, args.pretrainedModel)

        sess.run(
            [model['Optimizer'], model['iterator'].initializer],
                    feed_dict={model['x']:Xtrain,    
                               model['y']:Ytrain,
                               model['z']:Ytrain_em})
```

Comment: The pattern I'd follow is to (1) load the NumPy array, (2) run just the iterator initializer with the NumPy input as a feed, (3) remove references to the NumPy array so the memory is freed, (4) run the train op which consumes data. My impression from the question is that you're combining (2) and (4) while skipping (3), which seems like it'd keep multiple copies of the array while training, but please correct me if that's not the case.

Comment: @AllenLavoie how would you perform step (3) ? `np.delete` ?

Comment: I just mean releasing Python references to it, could be as simple as "del variable_name". As long as it's not part of a reference cycle it'll get cleaned up very quickly (if it is you'll need to break the cycle or run gc.collect()).